# Red5 stream flv file

Tags: stream, flv, red5

I was inspecting the oflaDemo from Red5.
I was wondering how I could change the oflaDemo so that I could stream a certain flv file to all the subscribers...

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params) {
        // Trigger calling of "onBWDone", required for some FLV players
        measureBandwidth(conn);
        if (conn instanceof IStreamCapableConnection) {
            IStreamCapableConnection streamConn = (IStreamCapableConnection) conn;
            SimpleConnectionBWConfig bwConfig = new SimpleConnectionBWConfig();
            bwConfig.getChannelBandwidth()[IBandwidthConfigure.OVERALL_CHANNEL] =
                1024 * 1024;
            bwConfig.getChannelInitialBurst()[IBandwidthConfigure.OVERALL_CHANNEL] =
                128 * 1024;
            streamConn.setBandwidthConfigure(bwConfig);
        }

            serverStream = StreamUtils.createServerStream(appScope, "live0");
            SimplePlayItem item = new SimplePlayItem();
            item.setStart(0);
            item.setLength(10000);
            item.setName("IronMan");
            serverStream.addItem(item);
            item = new SimplePlayItem();
            item.setStart(20000);
            item.setLength(10000);
            item.setName("DarkKnight");
            serverStream.addItem(item);
            serverStream.start();
            serverStream.setRepeat(true);

        return super.appConnect(conn, params);
    }
```

The result of the code above is just a blank screen for all subscribers...

Does anyone of you have any idea?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to accomplish on the client side and if you didn't want to hard-code the stream name, you could pass its name as a flash var.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I found that blank screen is because of what line

```
serverStream.setRepeat(true);
```

if you set repeat to false all works fine

**UPD:**
I think that this is red5 bug. I made a hack to repeat continiously one flv. I added custom play list controller:

```
public class MyPlayListController implements IPlaylistController {
    @Override
    public int nextItem(IPlaylist playlist, int itemIndex) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int previousItem(IPlaylist playlist, int itemIndex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```